# Where can I find some map or other resource that indicates which beaches in Taiwan are not recommended/allowed to swim at, preferably with the reason?

Tags: safety, regulations, taiwan, beaches, swimming

Swimming at some beaches in Taiwan is not recommended or not allowed due to drowning risks (strong currents/eddies/whirlpools/etc.) and/or pollution, e.g. swimming at [Shalun Beach](https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2012/07/15/2003537802) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20231227202412/https://www.taipeitimes.com/News/taiwan/archives/2012/07/15/2003537802)) near Taipei is not allowed. Where can I find some map or other resource that indicates which beaches in Taiwan are not recommended or not allowed to swim at, preferably with the reason for that recommendation/regulation?

---

Sign on Shalun Beach, from https://maps.app.goo.gl/RxUrsJTAVduFmxju6:

[image]